# OpenMP compiler flag thowing "file not found" errors

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp, catkin

I'm trying to compile OpenNN with openMP support in a catkin environment. I've compiled it without successfully however realised that my code was executing in a single thread.

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(opennn)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenMP)
if(OPENMP_FOUND)
message (STATUS “OpenMP found ${OpenMP_INCLUDE_DIRS}”) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS “${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}”)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS “${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}” )
else(OPENMP_FOUND)
message (STATUS “OpenMP not found”)
endif()



###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS src
  LIBRARIES opennn
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS other_catkin_pkg
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
 include_directories(include
    ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    /usr/include/eigen3

        )

## Declare a C++ library
add_library(opennn

    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/variables.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/instances.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/missing_values.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/data_set.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/plug_in.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/ordinary_differential_equations.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/mathematical_model.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/inputs.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/outputs.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/unscaling_layer.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/scaling_layer.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/probabilistic_layer.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/perceptron_layer.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/perceptron.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/neural_network.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/multilayer_perceptron.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/independent_parameters.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/conditions_layer.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/bounding_layer.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/sum_squared_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/solutions_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/root_mean_squared_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/performance_term.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/performance_functional.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/outputs_integrals.cpp
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/normalized_squared_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/neural_parameters_norm.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/minkowski_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/mean_squared_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/inverse_sum_squared_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/independent_parameters_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/final_solutions_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/cross_entropy_error.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/training_strategy.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/training_algorithm.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/training_rate_algorithm.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/random_search.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/quasi_newton_method.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/newton_method.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/levenberg_marquardt_algorithm.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/gradient_descent.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/evolutionary_algorithm.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/conjugate_gradient.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/testing_analysis.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/model_selection.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/numerical_integration.cpp 
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/numerical_differentiation.cpp
    src/${PROJECT_NAME}/tinyxml2.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(opennn ${Eigen_LIBRARIES})
```

and this is throwing the following errors at compile time:

```
  Building CXX object opennn/CMakeFiles/opennn.dir/src/opennn/missing_values.cpp.o
Building CXX object opennn/CMakeFiles/opennn.dir/src/opennn/data_set.cpp.o
c++: error: “: No such file or directory
[ 14%] c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
/bin/sh: 1: -fopenmp”: not found
c++: error: “: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [opennn/CMakeFiles/opennn.dir/src/opennn/missing_values.cpp.o] Error 127
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You have strange quote chars (“). Use normal quotes ("). (Use a plain text editor or an IDE, not something like Word, to edit code.)

Comment: In any problem with cmake-generated Makefile, use `make VERBOSE=1` to get log of actual commands issued by make.

Comment: @Mat he/she may simply have a too advanced keyboard layout. E.g. I can type symbols like « » (Russian typography quotes), as well as other rare symbols including two or three different kinds of spaces and dashes in any place including this comment. But certainly I did configure carefully the keyboard layout to get this :)

Comment: @Mat, good pickup. I'd copy and pasted that entry from a website, would not have noticed the quotes, but thats where the formatting came from.